# Can you help me list where the basic data structures used and how important they are to a programmer?

Tags: data-structures

Can you help me list where the basic data structures used and how important they are to a programmer?

In my codes, I always find nothing about basic data structures. How I should use them, I should learn what basic data structures and learn to what extend.

I really confuse with it.

Answer (score 1):

The names of the most basic data structures are arrays, arraylists, linked lists, maps, just to name a few. Start googling these, you should be able to find a lot about them, since they are used everywhere.

As per your question about what extent you should learn them, learn as many of them as possible, and learn as much as possible about each. This is necessary in order to decide which to use where.

For the rest, just do research. There are lots of resources on the net and in books with the answers to your questions.